# Angular 2 : prevent submit when input field is required in the page, using FormControl

Tags: angular, validation, input, form-control

I haven't used a form tag to wrap the input, where i want to validate that input on the submit click

i tried using FormControl, i didn't get an idea to stop submitting the value, it gets submitted.

The code i tried is below

```
<div class="dead-line">
<span class="p-gap">To delivery in this period I want to recevive orders until 
    <a (click)="deadlineTime(i)" class="del-r">
    <input type="date" class="form-control hide-dt"  [formControl]="deadlineVal" required>
    {{i.dead_line_time}}</a>
    </span>
    </div>
  <button class="bt-save" (click)="submitHomeDelivery()">Save</button>
```

.ts

```
  deadlineVal: FormControl = new FormControl('',
           [Validators.required]);

submitHomeDelivery() {

    var self = this;
    console.log('self.deadlineVal',  self.deadlineVal);
---------------------
---------------------
```

how could i prevent submitting(force input to be added), Any idea will appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Add disabled attribute to your button by marking a function and return value (True/False) according to your requirement.

Below will the example if you are using Angular 1.x

```
<button class="bt-save" ng-disabled = "allowButtonClick()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for validatoin like this.

```
submitHomeDelivery() { 
     if(this.deadlineVal.invalid) {
         return;
      }

     // do submit form here when form control is valid.

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm getting **invalid:true** in both cases, any idea of why its been happening?

Comment: Remove the html valdaton in the html input tag. (required)

Comment: @ Anuradha Gunasekara , no change

Answer (score 0):

Just add some function which returns True/False like this

```
  <button class="bt-save" (click)="submitHomeDelivery()" [disabled]='checkDisabled()'>Save</button>

checkDisabled() {
     return !this.deadlineVal.valid
}
```

You can Add expression to your HTML as well if you conditions are less else call function as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `[disabled]="!deadlineVal.valid"` to your button.

```
<button class="bt-save"
    (click)="submitHomeDelivery()"
    [disabled]="!deadlineVal.valid">Save</button>
```

Comment: asyncValidator
:
null
dirty
:
false
disabled
:
false
enabled
:
true
errors
:
Object
invalid
:
true
parent
:
undefined
pending
:
false
pristine
:
true
root
:
(...)
status
:
(...)
statusChanges
:
(...)
touched
:
(...)
untouched
:
true
valid
:
false

getting the console like this , thats an issue, even after in addition